# How to set high value clustered feature to the front?

Tags: openlayers-2

Here is the clustered vector layer I just added to the map.

```
var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        strokeColor     : "#FFFFFF",
        strokeOpacity   : 1,
        strokeWidth     : 2,
        fillColor       : settings.color,
        fillOpacity     : 0.9,
        cursor          : "pointer",
        pointRadius     : "${point_radius}",
        pointerEvents   : "visiblePainted",
        label           : "${label}",
        fontColor       : "#000000",
        fontSize        : "12px",
        fontFamily      : "verdana",
        fontWeight      : "bold",
        labelAlign      : "center" 
    }, {
        context: {
            label: function(feature) {
                var sumValue = 0;
                if(feature.attributes.count>1) {
                    for (var i=0; i<feature.cluster.length; i++) {
                        sumValue++;
                    }
                    return sumValue;
                }else{
                    return 1;
                }
            },
            point_radius: function(feature) {
                var pix = 10;
                if(feature.cluster) {
                    pix =Math.min(feature.attributes.count, 30) * 2.5 + 8;
                }
                return pix;
            }
        }
    });

    var onSelectStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        strokeColor     : "#000000",
        fontColor       : "#FFFFFF",
        pointerEvents   : "visiblePainted",
        fontSize        : "15px"
    });

    var strategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({distance: 30, threshold: 2});

    var ly=new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(GSMapLayerName,{
            strategies: [strategy],
            styleMap:new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                        "default":defaultStyle,
                        "select": onSelectStyle
                    }),
            displayInLayerSwitcher:false
        });
    map.addLayer(ly);
```

I am getting the below output

[image]

Look at the image the feature which have 9 is behind the 3 and 5. This is not a good to view.
 So, How can I set this feature to the front of all other features?

Note: I am using Openlayers 2.11

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
    var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        strokeColor     : "#FFFFFF",
        strokeOpacity   : 1,
        strokeWidth     : 2,
        fillColor       : settings.color,
        fillOpacity     : 0.9,
        cursor          : "pointer",
        pointRadius     : "${point_radius}",
                                            graphicZIndex   : "${point_radius}"
        pointerEvents   : "visiblePainted",
        label           : "${label}",
        fontColor       : "#000000",
        fontSize        : "12px",
        fontFamily      : "verdana",
        fontWeight      : "bold",
        labelAlign      : "center" 
    },
    ...................
    ......................

   var ly=new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(GSMapLayerName,{
            strategies: [strategy],
            styleMap:new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                        "default":defaultStyle,
                        "select": onSelectStyle
                    }),
            displayInLayerSwitcher:false,
            // enable the indexer by setting zIndexing to true
            rendererOptions: {zIndexing: true}
        });
    map.addLayer(ly);
```

Just add `graphicZIndex : "${point_radius}"` to the style and add `rendererOptions: {zIndexing: true}` to the layer.

Answer (score 2):

What if you try to add zIndex to the style with ${point_radius} as value?

Otherwise, check out http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/ordering.html